# Is it possible to load a dynamic video or playlist into the "featured" player of a YouTube Channel using URL parameters?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I'm running ads on various platforms (FB, Outbrain, etc.) to several different videos and playlists in my YouTube channel.

However, it's extremely important to me that these videos play out of the "featured" player on my channel landing page, so the user is exposed to our full branding, bio, list of shows, social follow links, etc.

Note, by "featured" player, I mean the player that appears directly on the channel landing page, e.g., `http://www.youtube.com/chow/` (this is not my channel, just an example).

Is it possible to use URL parameters or similar to load a specific, dynamic video or playlist into this main player? `e.g. http://www.youtube.com/chow/?v=XXXX&feature=playlist&list=XXXX`

Answer (score 2):

No.

You cannot "link-load" a video into the player. In general, the entire concept of a fully branded landing page on YouTube has been discontinued with the removal of the "everything happens on-channel"-concept Channels 2.0 had and fully removed when custom tabs for brand channels got axed.

What you can do instead is have your own website on which you embed the video.